# F8 failed to show startup menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, safe-mode

Running Windows 10 Pro 64bit I tried many times to press `F8` or `Shift` + `F8` but I could not display startup menu to choose safe mode, please advise what I should do, I need to choose safe mode because there is a problem with nVidia driver and I can not do that from inside Windows.

I have fast boot disabled.

Comment: Is the system on an SSD?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Yes.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F8 key is not enabled by default during bootup in Windows 10. You can enable this functionality if you want by entering the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

You can also boot into safe mode one-time by choosing this option in the Recovery settings under 'Update & Security' and through other methods including `msconfig`. See [this link](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, 
If I can not login into windows and I dont have installation CD then I can not do anything !!

Comment: Yes you can. Check out the link, one of the methods is to build a bootable USB stick, boot from it and then action safe mode from there.

Comment: creating recovery drive require a working windows 10

Comment: I have not tried it, but the safe mode boot instruction may work from a Windows 8 USB. If you have access to a Windows 8 machine you could build a USB stick and give it a try.